# From a light house $L$ two ships $P$ and $Q$ are observed in direction South West and $5^{\circ}$ East of South respectively. At same time $Q$.......

Tags: trigonometry

Question :

From a light house $L$ two ships $P$ and $Q$ are observed in direction South West and $5^{\circ}$ East of South respectively. At same time $Q$ is observed from point $P$ in South East direction of $LP =4$, prove that distance between ships is $4\sqrt{3}$

My approach :

Angle which $L$ makes with $P$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as it is South West  and angle $Q$ from $P$ is also $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as it is South East , please suggest how to prove this further.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this question is presented correctly? It seems to me the data are inconsistent. If ship Q were in a direction $15^\circ$ east of south relative to the lighthouse then I think the answer would be as stated. Are you sure it is supposed to be $5^\circ$ rather than $15^\circ$?